# Need to control "Z Order" of windows within WPF Application

Tags: wpf, user-interface, window, z-order

I have an application that, due to OpenGL airspace issues, has to host several controls in separate, exclusive windows. This is working quite well, but I am setting all of the windows to `TopMost = true`, which means that they do stay showing even when they lose focus, but they also overlay other applications. Also, it kind of binds me to using only one window at a time for this. `Activate()` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting the windows' owners to the main app window allowed them to always float on top.

Inside the control that mediates the content and measurement of the child window:

```
InnerWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

`this` being the windowHostControl hosting this window.

Answer (score 0):

I use to combine Activate() and Focus() methods to show a hidden Window. Can you try using Focus() and let us know if this is working ?